# BULK COLLECT INTO a UNION query into a table of objects

Tags: oracle, plsql, union, bulk-collect

How can I collect into a table of objects, the values produced by a query that has a union in it as shown below

```
Select customer_name
from customer
where customer_id = 'xxx'
BULK COLLECT INTO customer_obj
UNION
Select customer_name
from customer
where customer_name like '%adam%'
```

the constraints above are completely made up.

Comment: Better yet, just use a single SELECT and incorporate both WHERE conditions.

Comment: @Robert Harvey the actual query - everything about it from the table of objects and the constraints is very complicated - I just simplified it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bulk collect` clause comes right after the (first) `select` clause, before the (first) `from` clause. You have it in the wrong place.

It is not clear why you are using a `union` (although that by itself will **not** result in an error). Perhaps as an *unintended* consequence, you will get a list of **distinct** names, because that is what `union` does (as opposed to `union all`).

Other than that, as has been pointed out in a Comment already, you don't need `union` - you need an `or` in the `where` clause. But even if you modify your query that way, you still must move `bulk collect` to its proper place.

Comment: Hi, the UNION is not avoidable (to give you an idea, it is used to select two distinct rows which will be used for comparison with each other in the subsequent logic) - I just simplified the query this way - the actual logic is much too complicated.

Comment: My only concern is, if I use the bulk collect in the fist part of the union, will it also hold the rows selected by the second half of the union SQL?

Comment: @Murali - Yes. Also, this is something you can test yourself, easily.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to put your `UNION` into an inline view. For example,

```
SELECT          cust.customer_name 
BULK            COLLECT 
INTO            customer_obj
FROM (
  SELECT        customer_name
  FROM          customer
  WHERE         customer_id = 'xxx'
  UNION
  SELECT        customer_name
  FROM          customer
  WHERE         customer_name LIKE '%adam%'
) cust
```